# Swift - Using Core Data With Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

I'm playing with `Core Data` for an OS X application.  The language is `Swift`.  There's something odd about the way it works for `Cocoa`.  The following is a shorter version of what Xcode creates.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. (The directory for the store is created, if necessary.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var failError: NSError? = nil
        var shouldFail = false
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

        // Make sure the application files directory is there
        do {
            let properties = try self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.resourceValuesForKeys([NSURLIsDirectoryKey])
            if !properties[NSURLIsDirectoryKey]!.boolValue {
                failureReason = "Expected a folder to store application data, found a file \(self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.path)."
                shouldFail = true
            }
        } catch  {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            if nserror.code == NSFileReadNoSuchFileError {
                do {
                    try fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                } catch {
                    failError = nserror
                }
            } else {
                failError = nserror
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

And an SQLite file for Core Data is nowhere to be found after I add a new record to an entity.  There's no pointer to an SQLite file in the code above.  The following is an iOS counterpart.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()
}
```

The code above points to an SQLite file.  So I don't have trouble inserting a record to an entity.

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this an Xcode bug?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that's causing you trouble.  The code above looks like the auto-generated app delegate stuff that Xcode puts in.  Where's your code that you are attempting to add a record?

Comment: If you are saying you need a pointer to a SQLite file because you are going to edit the database directly, you have fundamentally misunderstood how Core Data works and how you should be using it. Can you explain further what you expect to happen with your code, and what you're actually observing?

Comment: Why don't you use the code Xcode creates for you?

Comment: @vadian I've said that that's a shorter version of what Xcode creates.

Comment: @Duncan Babbage I've tried to insert a record to an entity in the same manner I have done for iOS.  But the application doesn't create a database file.  So I've checked the code that Xcode has generated in AppDelegate.swift, which doesn't contain a path to an SQLite in contrast to iOS AppDelegate.swift.

Comment: The url is in the original `persistentStoreCoordinator`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted here is only part of a functional Core Data stack, and is insufficient to initialise Core Data.

This is Apple's current example code for initialising a Core Data Stack:

```
import CoreData
class DataController: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    init() {
        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
        guard let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DataModel", withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }
        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
            let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
            /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
             This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
             */
            let storeURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
            do {
                try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [Initialising the Core Data Stack](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1) from Apple.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  So it does include the SQLite file path.  Why don't I get it, do you know?  And what is your Xcode version?

Answer (score 1):

The **Swift 3** version of @DuncanBabbage solution:

```
class DataController: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    override init() {
        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataModel", withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }
        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async {
            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
            /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
             This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
             */
            let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
            do {
                try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```